# How to turn android proximity sensor on and off using togglebutton

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I made an MP3 Player app that uses the proximity sensor to change songs. I decided I wanted to update it and add the ability to disable the sensor using a Toggle Button. I tried using this code:

```
 case R.id.toggleButton1:
            if (toggleButton1.isChecked()) 
            {
                sm.unregisterListener(this);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proximity Sensor Off!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
```

I registered the listener up further in the code. When I run the app now, the listener is already disabled. I want it to be enabled by default unless the user selects the toggle button. Any help would be appreciated...thanks so much!

Comment: Please post your code, where you registering the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

sm.unregisterListener(*this*); 
as youre probably calling it from onClickListener, *this* means the actual OnClickListener instead of proximysensor listener

Comment: So are you trying to say to call it outside of the onClick, or to change how I call the unregisterListener?

Comment: you need to unregister your outter listener, so you cant use the word this, which means the class youre calling it from, not the class(listener) you want to call. Make a reference to your proximity sensor listener and pass it in sm.unregistereListener

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener,
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor proximitySensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        proximitySensor = sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (proximitySensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, proximitySensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked && proximitySensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, proximitySensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        } else {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```